# What am I supposed to be?

Tags: riddle, word

This one is probably very easy. I'm still trying to getting the hang of more complex structures :)

```
I hover, I freeze,

I mourn, I cry,

I move, I fade,

my color shapes your mood,

when I'm not there you feel warmth.
```

Alternative final line (only as an assist):

> when I'm not there you feel the sun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's

> clouds

I hover, I freeze,

> Clouds are above us thus hovering the earth
>  Sometimes, they produce snow and hail

I mourn, I cry,

> Sometimes, they produce rain

I move, I fade,

> They move with the wind, and they fade when there is no water anymore.

my color shapes your mood,

> When they are grey they can make you sad, when they are red (sunrise or sunset) they make you happy

when I'm not there you feel warmth.

> When they are not here, they are not in the way of the sun's warmth.

Comment: That's it! I'll try to produce harder ones in the future, haha :P